# keep li:before top align on two lines

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I used a li:before as an information tag. works perfect, the thing is that when the li is two lines long, the li:before moves to the seconf line and doesnt stay with the bullet.

Its kinda hard to explain, but I attached a picture with the difference

[image]

How can I force the li:before stay pointing the bullet??

HTML:

```
<div class="contentContenedor">
    <div class="tituloContentContenedor">Box: Promociones nacionales</div>
    <div class="linksContentContenedor">
           <ul>
               <li>Vuela barato por Chile
                <span class="linksContentContenedorClicks">752</span>
               </li>
                <li>Encántate con el sur de nuestro país
                <span class="linksContentContenedorClicks">178</span>
                </li>
                 <li>Disfruta el norte de Chile
                 <span class="linksContentContenedorClicks">106</span>
                 </li>
                  <li>Canjea tus kms. y vuela por Chile
                  <span class="linksContentContenedorClicks">87</span>
                 </li>
            </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.contentContenedor{
    background-image:url('img/fondo_cajas_home.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center bottom; 
    width:270px;
    height:140px;
    margin-left:60px;

}
.tituloContentContenedor{
    background-image:url('img/fondo_tit_cajas_home_270_23.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:270px;
    height:23px;
    color:white;
    font:bold 11px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    padding:6px 0px 2px 11px;
}
.linksContentContenedor{
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#0267C3;
    margin-top:1px;
}
.linksContentContenedor ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    margin-left:28px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
.linksContentContenedor li{
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
.linksContentContenedorClicks {
    position: absolute;
    right: 115%;
    width: auto;
    height: 16px;
    background: #033D7D;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
    padding-left:4px;
}

.linksContentContenedorClicks:before {
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    border-left: 15px solid #033D7D;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
}
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the pseudo-selector `:before` applied on any `li`. It is used on all the spans containing the click count value, via the `linksContentContenedorClicks` class. There's no problem with it.

Since you have `linksContentContenedorClicks` absolutely positioned inside the relatively positioned `li` elements, you probably want to add `top: 0;` so they will always stick to the top of the surrounding `li`.

```
.linksContentContenedorClicks {
    position: absolute;
    right: 115%;
    top: 0; /* this was missing */
    width: auto;
    height: 16px;
    background: #033D7D;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
    padding-left:4px;
}
```

Comment: I keep thinking my answer fits better but as you wish... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `span` elements before the text in you `li`s and **don't** add `top: 0`

This way you keep line-height and all the text alignments.

```
       <ul>
           <li>
               <span class="linksContentContenedorClicks">752</span>Vuela barato por Chile
           </li>
       </ul>
```